# What are good practices for displaying variables in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript and Jquery.

I am using Jquery $.ajax for sending get request, dealing with returned Json String and use `.html()` to display contents in `<div id="myTabs"></div>` in my html. You can see from my code below, I am using a String variable to make a HTML  list. Am I doing this in a good practice? I feel this way is not very agile, Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks!

```
function updateRelated(str)
{
    $.ajax(
        {
            url:ServerUrl+api_subject,
            type:'GET',
            success:function(json)
            {
                // alert(json);
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

                var toDisplay="";
                var tableDisplay="<ul>";
                for(var i=0;i<obj.subject_list.length;i++)
                {
                    tableDisplay=tableDisplay+'<li><a href="subject.htm?subjectid='+obj.subject_list[i].id+'">'+obj.subject_list[i].title+'</li>';
                    //    toDisplay=toDisplay+"<br>preferred_synonym:"+obj.relatedCocepts[i].preferred_synonym+",Type: "+obj.relatedCocepts[i].type+",score: "+obj.relatedCocepts[i].score;
                }
                tableDisplay=tableDisplay+"</ul>"
                $("#myTabs").html(tableDisplay);
            }
        }
        )
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically i'm reading your question to be really asking whether or not you should be writing a string of markup and outputting it into the dom, with variables concatted into it.

Its ok to do for smaller stuff, but if you're writing a lot of views with javascript, you'll want a tool for putting together view partials.

There are tools out there that do this:

- http://mustache.github.com/
- https://github.com/adammark/Markup.js
- http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Comment: Stay away from jQuery templates. The project was deprecated almost two years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a templating engine like [jsViews](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/). If you insist on looping and creating elements with jQuery, take a look at: http://www.andyjarrett.co.uk/blog/index.cfm/2009/3/14/Creating-a-new-DOM-element-with-jQuery/ - the syntax is easy:

```
div = $("<div>"); // then append more stuff with append() or html()
```

But again, if you're appending a ton of stuff, using a templating engine is by far superior to a home-brewed looping solution. It's also more robust and extensible (and layout modifications are easier to implement).

Answer (score 1):

Like other people already said, a template engine is the way to go if you have lots of html. But you can clean your current code by using an array. I commented a few things:

```
var list = [],
    arr = obj.subject_list,
    len = arr.length; // cache length for better performance

for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
  list.push(
    '<li>'+
      '<a href="subject.htm?subjectid='+ arr[i].id +'">'+
        arr[i].title +
      '</a>'+ // you forgot to close <a>
    '</li>'
  );
}

$("#mytabs").html('<ul>'+ list.join('') +'</ul>');
```

When dealing with html in JavaScript I recommend indenting your html properly just as if it were real html. As you can see it's much more readable and you can avoid syntax errors, like the missing closing `</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you are doing a fine job here, in this case i would probabaly do something very similar. Using a special plugin is possible, and probably more user friendly, but they almost always come with a lot of overhead. I doubt this could be done more efficient in terms of processor load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsrender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) for this.

Define a template within a script tag using the special type `text/x-jsrender`:

```
<script id="listTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <li><a href="subject.htm?subjectid={{>id}}">{{>title}}</a></li>
</script>
```

Notice that it's easy to see the structure of your HTML.  Less opportunity to miss things as opposed to concatenating in javascript (you missed the closing `</a>` tag, BTW).

To use this template, modify your function like this:

```
success:function(json)
{
    // alert(json);
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
    var htmlList = $('#listTemplate').render(obj.subject_list);
    $('#myTabs').html(htmlList);   
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d4DjY/.  Mousing over the links you can see they have the correct id's in the querystring.

More demos here: http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/demos.html.  Use view-source to see the template code.

Answer (score -1):

You could also take a look at [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).  It's still in beta, and not going any further than that, but for your situation, it should be fine.

Comment: jQuery Templates has been deprecated. Avoid.

Comment: FWIW, jQuery Templates are used by the just released [outlook.com](https://outlook.com).  It may not have active development but it's still pretty functional.